# How refresh power BI desktop reports when data changed?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have developed several reports in power bi desktop and published them to PowerBi.com. Is there any way that I can refresh the power bi desktop when data changed or can schedule it ?

Comment: You need a pro license and install on premises data gateway, or use direct query

Comment: Actually you can refresh daily using the Free license: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/

Comment: can we  refresh a reports automatically every data updation without scheduling refresh time?

Answer (score 1):

You need a pro license to refresh power BI reports. Once you have it you need to install ON PREMISES Data gateway or use direct query.